# How to call one mvc project controller API to another mvc project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api

I have two MVC projects in single solution . Now i have to call project1 controller API in project2 using angular js post/get method. I have tried to mention project1 url in project2. But getting "405 Method not allowed.". I have tried in Postman with same url and same parameter. That time API was called. How to resolve it.

Comment: Place the full url in JS?, Both project are running?

Comment: yes, i did it. both projects in running